# What is the definition of a "spacecraft emergency" at the ISS, and what is the response to it?

Tags: iss, procedure, emergency

Several sources including the [Orange County Register](https://www.ocregister.com/2021/07/29/international-space-station-briefly-loses-control/) are reporting that a "spacecraft emergency" was declared today onboard the ISS due to the new MLM module's uncommanded thruster firings after docking.

[image: humorous image of a man shouting into a megaphone. He wears an orange track suit and a helmet with a flashing light on it.]

What does it mean that a "spacecraft emergency" was declared? What happens onboard the ISS?  Is there a specific response?

Image source: Cropped screen capture from [Kentucky Fried Movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076257/reference)

Comment: I'm assuming this is an ask-to-answer type of question. I await your answer. I work on the design side rather than the ops side of things, so I can't provide a good answer. We generally design thrusters to fail off: Multiple valves in series, software and firmware that are carefully scrutinized. A failed on thruster ranks right up there in the hierarchy of bad things we do not want to ever happen in space.

Comment: @DavidHammen No, I don't know the answer in today's world. It was a pretty incredible scenario including a 45 minute LOAC. There hasn't been one of those in a long time. The design people swore up and down shuttle jets couldn't fail on. MLM appears to be different.

Comment: I'm not ops, but I would call a thruster fail on that causes a 45 minute loss of attitude control an emergency. Thrusters are not supposed to turn on "inadvertently". And for 45 minutes? Wow.

Comment: I would imagine if the flight controller says it's an emergency then it's declared one.

Comment: Thrusters firing uncommanded go all the way back to Gemini VIII. The crew only got back alive because of the skill of the Command Pilot, who three years later walked on the Moon.

Comment: @GordonD Those inadvertent firings on Gemini 8 were a huge lesson-learned in how **not** to design thrusters. I worked on a much later vehicle on detecting and correcting for thruster failures. I asked whether I needed to worry about thrusters failing on. I was told thrusters don't fail on. A few weeks later, the avionics team said they had found some circumstances where thrusters could fail on. This was not a happy moment for the avionics team. It was easy to find the project lead: Listen for where all the shouting was coming from. There was a lot of shouting in that meeting.

Comment: GdD "the" flight controller? Which one?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Presumably the flight director. Flight ops is a hierarchical organization.

Comment: @DavidHammen I would think so too, but Flight isn't usually referred to as a "controller'.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The name changed from Mission Control to Flight Control a few years ago. I don't know why, but it did.

Comment: @DavidHammen the name of what?

Comment: What was JSC's Mission Operations Directorate is now the Flight Operations Directorate.

Comment: @DavidHammen it's actually FOD (lol) Flight Operations Directorate. Used to be MOD back in my day.

Comment: I fixed that mistake, @OrganicMarble.

Comment: A spacecraft emergency is about [540 Scovilles](https://www.space.com/nauka-module-space-station-tilt-more-serious) ([Scoville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoville_scale))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly the term encompasses many protocols, but at least one effect is detailed [here](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/iss-operating_an_outpost-tagged.pdf):

> [Spacecraft Emergency] is a protocol that the Ground
> Controller (GC), who is responsible
> for the MCC infrastructure as well as
> interface to the NASA Space Network,
> invokes with the Space Network to
> make sure the ISS gets all available
> satellite communications assets
> and bumps other users from using
> those assets.
>
> If the ISS Program suddenly
> needs TDRS coverage—such as for
> an emergency spacewalk—the NASA
> flight director can declare the TDRS
> time as critical, thereby forcing
> other users off the network. Due to
> the impacts to other uses, which can
> include loss of science, this is not
> done unless absolutely required.

The ISS is not unique in the ability to call a TDRS emergency; see for instance the [THEMIS satellite](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1357&context=smallsat).

Comment: [Space station situation with Russian module misfire more serious than stated: report](https://www.space.com/nauka-module-space-station-tilt-more-serious)